# 500 server error from application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm working with the [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem.

One of the first steps in setup is including the required css and js in my asset pipeline:

In application.js, I added:

```
 *= require s3_direct_upload
```

In application.css, I added:

```
//= require s3_direct_upload_progress_bars
```

I bundle installed, and restarted my server, but when I hit my application I'm seeing this:

[image]

None of these assets are being found. Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: Check out your log file. `log/environmentyouareusing.log`  That will give you more information about the errors.  You might want to post that file as well if you are still having trouble tracking down the errors.

Comment: I checked log/development.log but file is blank. I did some more testing and noticed that even when I add a new js/css directly into my assets folder its not getting picked up.

Comment: It was an issue with memcache. I didn't have it running locally. Once I booted it up with "/usr/local/bin/memcached" it found the new assets just fine.